# Get indexPath of mapView annotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview, mkpinannotationview

When an annotation on the map is selected and the callout accessory control button is tapped I need to be able to find the index of that annotation. The index is going to be used to look at information in an array to prepare for the next view controller (detailed).

How do I find the index of an annotation?

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
NSLog(@"Button clicked");
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: try to set the tag for each Annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MKAnnotationView * view = ...

NSUInteger index = [mapView.annotations indexOfObject:view.annotation];

Comment: This will give the index of the annotation in the map view's list of annotations but it is unsafe to assume that position matches with one's own array of annotations.  Using a custom annotation class with the data needed already embedded in it (or referenced in it) is the preferred approach as @nevan king suggests.

Comment: I created a custom annotation class that now stores the description. If I do NSLog(@"%@", mapView.annotations.description);  it prints out the description for all annotation. How do I do it for the one selected only.

Answer (score 3):

It has no index path like there is in a table view. Use your own model class as an annotation by making it conform to `MKAnnotation`, then use whatever logic you have for tracking individual model items. Or just pass the model item as-is to the next view controller.

Comment: Have you got an example? I don't understand your answer.

Comment: What is the class of the thing you are adding to the map? i.e. do you have a "Shop" class or something similar?

Comment: I have an array that stores multiple objects containing title, subtitle, description and address. I have a for loop that iterates  through the array for the address element and plots it on the map. I want to be able to display the description for that array index on my next view controller.

Comment: Then whatever is in the array is your model. Make it a real class and add `<MKAnnotation>` in the .h file. Check the Apple sample code for Map Callouts for an example of packing things into an annotation.